# How to execute playwright commands in vscode debug console

Tags: visual-studio-code, playwright

I'm debugging a playwright test written in Node inside vscode.
When the execution is halted on a breakpoint, I want to execute playwright commands in the debug console such as

```
await page.click("css=.some-button");
```

But it doesn't seems to work.

I've executed playwright commands inside the debug console, but it doesn't work

Comment: what exactly happens?